# Probability, counting and permutation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am trying to answer this question:

The letters of the word TROGLODYTE are arranged at random. Find the probability that there are at least 7 letters separating “G” and “Y”.

I assumed the events:
A: having 7 letters separating “G” and “Y”
B: having 8 letters separating “G” and “Y”

P(A) =? For this we need to select 7 letters and treat G and those 7
letters and Y as 1 identity and then this 9 letter group and the rest 1
identity can be arranged in 2! ways, G and Y can interchange
their positions , this will be done in 2 ways and selection of 7
letters that could lie between G and Y could be done in ${C_8}^7$ ways, hence total number of ways this arrangement could be
done are $2!\times2!C_8^7$. Hence $$P(A)=\frac{2!\times2!C_8^7}{\frac{10!}{2!2!}}$$
and P(B) in the same manner.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way to calculate it is as follows. The two spaces filled by G and Y can be any of $\binom {10}2=45$ possibilities, with equal probability. There are $3$ of these possibilities which have at least $7$ spaces separating them (first and last, second and last, first and second last). So the answer is $3/45=1/15$.

(Here $\binom{10}2$ is an alternative notation for your $C_{10}^2$.)

Comment: Aren't you missing the fact that O and T appear twice

Comment: @Shashaank It doesn't matter. You have one G, one Y, and eight other letters. Success or failure just depends on how many other letters are between G and Y, not which ones.

Comment: according to your logic that looks correct but then what is wrong in my logic on the above answer

Comment: @Shashaank nothing's wrong with your logic - you get the same answer, after all - and I upvoted it earlier. It's not necessary to compute the number of different arrangements in this case, but it's a perfectly sound method.

Comment: that's what I thought but then if you would have a look at the comments there - I did 7! /2! 2! to account for the number of ways the inner 7 letters can be arranged. But a case may arise when either 1 O or 1 T is not in the inner seven letters... So for just P(A) two cases should arise.... One which I have included which is that both O and both T are in the inner 7 letters and the in the other case either 1 O or 1 T is not in the inner seven letters in that case the factor will be just 7! /2! .... This factor should be added too... But then it changes the totalanswer to 11/45

Comment: shouldn't that factor be added if you go by my method of counting all possible arrangements... Thanks for the upvote... I think the comment confused me on my logic itself.. I think that factor   should be added, isn't it

Comment: @Shashaank no, you still need to divide by $2!.2!$ whether or not the extra letter is an O (or T). The point is that if all the Os and Ts are in the seven, you need to divide by $2!2!$ for the arrangements of those seven, whereas if one of the Os (say) is not in the seven, you only need to divide by $2!$ for the arrangement of the seven, but you need to divide by another $2$ because it doesn't matter which O is inside and which outside.

Comment: Another way of thinking about it: you have eight spaces other than the G and Y spaces, and $\frac{8!}{2!2!}$ of arranging the other eight letters into those spaces. It doesn't matter (for the purpose of counting arrangements of those eight letters) that one of those spaces is outside and the rest inside.

Comment: yeah I got it... Thanks for the 2nd explanation... I thought initially along those lines that we " essentially just need to distribute 8 things on 8 places just that 2 things appear twice"... I have upvoted your answer... Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

The total number of distributions ie the sample space is just $\frac{10! }{2! 2! }$. If G and Y are fixed at any 2 places then you just need to distribute

1) 7 items in between them and 1 not between them ie you need to distribute a total of 8 items. The total ways to distribute is then $2\times 2\times \frac{8! }{2! 2! }$. The first 2 in the above is due the fact that G and Y can be swapped giving 2 possible ways and the second 2 is due to the fact the G and Y along with the group of 7 seven letters in between them can be either in front of the 10th letter or in the end of the 10th letter. This will happen for both cases when G is occuring before Y or the opposite hence $2\times2 = 4$ cases.

2) there are 8 items in between G and Y and the total number of arrangements is $2\times 1\times \frac{8! }{2! 2! }$

Hence the total probability is

$\frac{ 2\times 2\times \frac{8!}{2! 2!}}{\frac{10! }{2!2!}} + \frac{ 2\times 1\times \frac{8!}{2! 2!}}{\frac{10! }{2! 2! }} = \frac{1}{15}$

Note $ 8! =8 \times \; ^8C_7$

Comment: thank you, yeah sound more logical... but in the denominator shouldn't be 10!/2!2! because of the repetition of T and O ?

Comment: @RabihAssaf oops yeah you are correct about that... I didn't see the "alphabets" reoccuring... I have edited that

Comment: @RabihAssaf  also see the corresponding edits to 7! /2! 2!...so the answer will remain the same... albeit I have shown it exclusively and when I had worked it out I had simply thrown the factors of 2! 2! away

Comment: In the first fraction, in the numeratore why 7!/2!2! what if T and O are not both of them from the 7 letters? Shouldn't be two fraction 7!/2!2! and the second one 7!/2!.... the second fraction is good

Comment: @RabihAssaf  That is happening because when you are selecting 7 out of 8 $^8C_7$ you are forgetting that out of the 8 letters "O" and "T" repeat 2 times. If you expand each case ie a) when the 2 O's and 2 T's are in the 7 letters b) either 1 O or 1 T is not in the 7 letters ( this will bring a factor of 2 since either 1 O or 1 T will not be in the 7 letters)... Add all the cases you will get the same result.... albeit this will be longer

Comment: So we must add \frac{2!\times2! (7!/2!){C_8}^7}{\frac{10!}{2!2!} ?

Comment: @RabihAssaf  yes that looks correct.. But mind you 2 times that term should be added since either 1 O or 1 T can be outside that collection of 7 letters. But yes an extra term should be aadesh giving a factor of 8/45 which should be addef